# How to multiply simultaneously more than one rows with each other

Tags: matrix, code-review, code-request

I want to simultaneously multiply more than one rows with each other. Like 1 with 2 and 3 with 4 likewise.

```
Psi2[V1_] := Block[{mat1,i,j}, mat1 = ConstantArray[0, Length@mat];
    For[i = 1, i = Length@V1, i += 2, * 1st row
      For[j = 1, j = Length@V1, j += 1, * 2nd row
       mat1[[{i, j}]] = V1[[{i, i}]].V1[[{j, j}]];
      ];
    ];
   mat1 ];
```

Where V1 is a $20\times 20$ matrix. But this code didn't work.

*NOTE*: I want to multiply more than one row simultaneously.
Example:

\begin{matrix}
  a0 & b0 & c0 & d0 & e0\\
  a1 & b1 & c1 & d1 & e1 \\
  a2 & b2 & c2 & d2 & e2\\
  a3 & b3 & c3 & d3 & e3\\
  a4 & b4 & c4 & d4 & e4\\
  a5 & b5 & c5 & d5 & e5\\
 \end{matrix}
I want 
 \begin{matrix}
  a0a1 & b0b1 & c0c1 & d0d1 & e0e1\\
  a1 & b1 & c1 & d1 & e1 \\
  a2a3 & b2 b3 & c2c3 & d2d3 & e2e3\\
  a3 & b3 & c3 & d3 & e3\\
  a4a5 & b4. & c4. & d4. & e4e5\\
  a5 & b5 & c5 & d5 & e5\\
 \end{matrix}
"."(in fifth row) means continuation.

Comment: Why don't just you `mat^2`?  There are multiple strange things in your code aside from the fact that it is a very complicated and inefficient solution to a simple problem.  You are using global variables (`i`, `j`, `V1`) *within the functions* and almost not using the argument `mat`.  The number of columns is not `Length[V1]`. The  `.` sign is not multiplication, it's dot product.  You initialize `mat1` to a vector, not a matrix.

Comment: @Szabolcs But that is different from each elements square. Thanks for the important points. I will check them now.

Comment: No, it's exactly each element's square.

Comment: @lavkush. No. In *Mathematica* `mat^2` is the operation that squares `mat` element-wise. `mat.mat` is matrix multiplication,

Comment: @march Thanks for this. I think I forgot the basic matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Szabolcs In case if I need to multiply two different rows like 1 and 2 then 3 and 4 and so on. Will the above code work, with some modification.

Comment: I don't really understand your comment.  The above code doesn't even do what you wanted it to do.  As a start, forget that `For` even exists and use `Do` for procedural programming.  But try to avoid procedural programming whenever you can.  Look up `Table`.  Go through the beginning of this before continuing: https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks a lot. I will see this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you edited your question i have the answer for you:
Let $V$ be your Matrix (which has to have Even Dimensions)

```
(V[[#]]=V[[#]]*V[[#+1]])&/@Range[1,Length[V],2];
```

You`ll get:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \text{a}_1 \text{a}_2 & \text{b}_1 \text{b}_2 & \text{c}_1 \text{c}_2 & \text{d}_1 \text{d}_2 & \text{e}_1 \text{e}_2 & \text{f}_1 \text{f}_2 \\
 \text{a}_2 & \text{b}_2 & \text{c}_2 & \text{d}_2 & \text{e}_2 & \text{f}_2 \\
 \text{a}_3 \text{a}_4 & \text{b}_3 \text{b}_4 & \text{c}_3 \text{c}_4 & \text{d}_3 \text{d}_4 & \text{e}_3 \text{e}_4 & \text{f}_3 \text{f}_4 \\
 \text{a}_4 & \text{b}_4 & \text{c}_4 & \text{d}_4 & \text{e}_4 & \text{f}_4 \\
 \text{a}_5 \text{a}_6 & \text{b}_5 \text{b}_6 & \text{c}_5 \text{c}_6 & \text{d}_5 \text{d}_6 & \text{e}_5 \text{e}_6 & \text{f}_5 \text{f}_6 \\
 \text{a}_6 & \text{b}_6 & \text{c}_6 & \text{d}_6 & \text{e}_6 & \text{f}_6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: I think there is more to it. But I didn't understand your first $M$,  what two rows multiplication gave it.

Comment: It is good one. Much helpful

Answer (score 1):

Let's take

```
m = RandomInteger[10, {6, 6}]
```

> {{3, 7, 1, 1, 9, 5}, {0, 6, 3, 3, 9, 1}, {0, 5, 3, 0, 1, 8}, {0, 9, 0,
>      0, 8, 0}, {5, 6, 2, 10, 10, 2}, {7, 6, 2, 1, 6, 3}}

Then

```
Table[m[[i]] = m[[i]] m[[i + 1]], {i, 1, Length @ m - 1, 2}];
```

will replace some (i.e., every odd) rows with itself multiplied by the next row; e.g. first row $\rightarrow$ first row times second row; second row unchanged, etc. It **replaces** parts of `m`, hence now `m` is

```
m
```

> {{0, 42, 3, 3, 81, 5}, {0, 6, 3, 3, 9, 1}, {0, 45, 0, 0, 8, 0}, {0, 9,
>      0, 0, 8, 0}, {35, 36, 4, 10, 60, 6}, {7, 6, 2, 1, 6, 3}}

Comment: This helping me, much better than my wrong code.